# Connection Failure on login PHP

Tags: php, localhost, login-script

Not one part of me understands the issue with this code! It did work, and now it doesn't. I'm unable to login to the 'profile page' can anyone see and issue?

```
<?php
session_start(); 

$error=''; 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) 
    {
        $error = "Enter username & password";
    }
else {
    // Define $username and $password
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    echo($connection);
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    $db = mysql_select_db("Windsor", $connection);
        echo($db);      
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM PHP_Customer WHERE Email='$username' and Password='$password'";
        echo($sql);
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

            $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

            if ($count < 1) 
            {
                $error = "Username or Password is incorrect";
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['user_login'] = $username; 
                header('location: profile.php');
                echo "hello world!"; // This is just for testing purposes

            }
        } 
mysql_close($connection); 
}

?>
```

As i've said, it did work and for whatever reason it's seems to no longer.

Comment: any error you found here??

Comment: Please use mysli_* or PDO. because mysql_* is deprecated now. and also try to write mysql error code so that you come to know what error occur actually

Comment: None whatsoever, purely for debugging purposes i tried `   echo($sql);` to print the sql query if i put in the correct login details, nothing is shown. However, if i enter incorrect details the query is printed, like so `SELECT * FROM PHP_Customer WHERE Email='wrong' and Password='wrong password'`

Comment: What does `Resource id #61` refer too?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: that mean that you get the something.

Comment: you're also outputting with header and `echo "hello world!";` use one, not both.

Comment: *Ralph, bets on a server upgrade?* I wonder if PHP was upgraded without the OP's knowledge @Fred-ii-

Comment: *No lo so, mi amico Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: `@ me` if you need me. Sam and I will be sipping on cappucinos for a while, won't we Sam? @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a couple of issues.

1) You have a lower case "AND" in the statement. It should read:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM PHP_Customer WHERE Email='$username' AND Password='$password'";
```

2) Don't set mysql_select_db as a variable and echo it. That line should read:

```
mysql_select_db("Windsor", $connection);
```

3) Don't echo the connection details.

4) Add a bit of error checking to your mysql statements.

The script should now read as follows:

```
<?php
session_start(); 

$error=''; 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) 
    {
        $error = "Enter username & password";
    }
else {
    // Define $username and $password
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    mysql_select_db("Windsor", $connection) or die(mysql_error());      
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM PHP_Customer WHERE Email='$username' AND Password='$password'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

            $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

            if ($count < 1) 
            {
                $error = "Username or Password is incorrect";
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['user_login'] = $username; 
                header('location: profile.php');
                echo "hello world!"; // This is just for testing purposes

            }
        } 
mysql_close($connection); 
}

?>
```